# Gochugaru powder vs paste?

Tags: substitutions, chili-peppers, korean-cuisine, ingredients

I'm making Korean pork bulgogi and the recipe I am using calls for gochugaru powder but all I could find was a paste.

Can I use it and would it still be the same amount? The recipe asks for 4 tbsp. of the powder.

Comment: By "a paste", do you mean gochujang? (Sticky red paste, thicker than ketchup, sold in a red tub with a red or gold lid)

Comment: A quick scan of bulgogi recipes shows some use gochujang, some gochugaru & some use both. Quantities vary massively, depending on spice level.

Comment: Hey, folks, this is a NEW CONTRIBUTOR!  Maybe don't close her post without explaining how to fix it?

Comment: @mantra is right on, but if you want to add the recipe you're following, you might be able to get away with it here. T struck he that bulgogi marinades typically include some sugar? So you might be able to fiddle around with the amount of sweetener and use gochujang for your bulgogi after all.

Comment: Thank you all.. on the label it states its gochugaru and yes it is thicker than ketchup and comes in a red tub. I am looking for that sweet spicy flavor!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to gochujang, gochugaru and gochujang have significantly different flavors (gochugaru is thought to impart a "cleaner" hotness to dishes, while gochujang tends to be a bit more complex due to aspects like added sugar and grain e.g. rice flour (which adds a thickening element) and some fermentation.

Thus Korean recipes will often use both, and as a rule of thumb gochugaru is the more flexible of the two (due to being mainly used for only hotness and color). In addition, while gochujang is reasonably replaceable with gochugaru + some sweeteners and thickeners, trying to replace gochugaru with gochujang is generally a bad idea. I'd recommend trying a different kind of relatively fine red pepper flakes - preferably a less spicy and less "aromatic" (i.e. one that has few flavors and aromas outside of "hot") variety, although your mileage may very depending on the type your local market has.

Comment: Aleppo pepper is actually a pretty good substitute.  Ancho chile powder can also work.

Comment: I've actually used paprika and a pinch of cayenne in an emergency. Not perfect, but more readily available on my budget, sadlol.